# How to convert a multi-member Json on Dart?

Tags: json, string, flutter, dart, type-conversion

I'm getting a String(json) from a http.post, but the Json has multiple members separated by comma.
Like:

```
{"name":"John",
 "age":30,
 "car":null
},{
 "name":"Lisa",
 "age":20,
 "car":null
},{ etc...
```

I do:

```
var string = response.body;
var json = jsonDecode(String);
```

That works fine when I have just 1 member.
But when I get more than one (like in the example), I get the following error:

```
ERROR: FormatException: Unexpected character

"car":null"},{"name":"Lisa",
            ^
```

Any suggestions? Thanks <3

Comment: I believe the objects that are separated by the `,` will need to enclosed inside of an array (these brackets - `[]`). Can you confirm if they are members of a list?

Comment: Yeeees, you and @Apealed and Navid Shad were right. I wrote `var json = jsonDecode('[$string]');` and then: `print(json[0]['name']);` and I got the first name object and then `print(json[1]['name']);` and I got the second name object :) **Thanks guys.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should form the string like an array to make it parsable:

```dart
var string = response.body;
var json = jsonDecode('[$string]');
```